# For every $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a sequence $a_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with the following property: For every $p\in \mathbb{N}$ and every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and $m, n \leq m\leq n+p$ but $a_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

I believe that $a_n=\sqrt n$ would work but I am having a hard time formalizing the work.

Comment: Indeed it would. It boils down to finding an $N$ with $\sqrt{N+p} - \sqrt{N} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Ok. I thought it was just me. Would I need to solve for $N$ from the inequality and then use it?

Comment: I don't know whether you need to do that, but it's how I would go about it. And then use properties of the square root to prove that the sequence indeed has all the required properties.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $q_n \to 0$ and are positive and decreasing, let
$$
a_n = \sum \limits_{j \leq n} q_j.
$$

$$0 < a_{n+p} - a_n = \sum \limits_{n < j \leq n+p} q_j \leq p q_n.$$

The last goes to zero so your property holds.

But if $q_n = 1/n$, $a_n \to \infty.$

Comment: Can you provide more details so that I can follow from the problem statement to your answer?